# Making an image based on integer matrix and colormap

Tags: r

I'm working under R and would like to do the following.

I have a matrix with in its entries integer ranging from 1 to n. Furthermore I have a named list mapping the integers 1,2,3...,n to colors

```
c('white':1, 'black':2, 'pink':3, ...., 'purple':n)
```

What I want is to write a jpeg to my disk with the same resolution as my matrix and in each pixel the color that corresponds to the integer in the entry of the matrix according to the named list.

For example I would like a corresponding 5 by 5 jpeg for the following matrix and colormap.

```
col = c('0':'white', '1':'yellow', '2':'black', '3':'green')

A = matrix( round(runif(min = 0, max = 3, n = 25)), nrow = 5)
```

I have tinkered around with the EBImage package and raster package, but thus far I have not been able to find a way to do this.

Does anybody have some code that achieves this or have any suggestions?

Comment: You should provide a small example. E.g. a 5x5 matrix and corresponding color list.

Comment: Did just that, but I don't know if it really clarifies the question

Comment: `col = c('0':'white', '1':'yellow', '2':'black', '3':'green')` is not valid R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned by @RobertHijmans, `c('0':'white', '1':'yellow', '2':'black', '3':'green')` is not valid R.

Use a vector of colors:

```
colors <- c('white', 'yellow', 'black', 'green')
```

The matrix of integers:

```
A <- matrix( round(runif(min = 0, max = 3, n = 25)), nrow = 5)
```

Convert it to the matrix of corresponding colors:

```
Acolors <- apply(A, 1:2, function(i) colors[i+1])
```

This gives:

```
> Acolors
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]    
[1,] "green"  "yellow" "black"  "white"  "yellow"
[2,] "yellow" "black"  "yellow" "yellow" "white" 
[3,] "black"  "yellow" "black"  "yellow" "yellow"
[4,] "white"  "black"  "black"  "yellow" "black" 
[5,] "yellow" "black"  "black"  "black"  "yellow"
```

Now, apply the function `rasterImage`:

```
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(0, 0, type = "n", xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1), asp=1, 
     axes=FALSE, xlab=NA, ylab=NA)
rasterImage(Acolors, 0, 0, 1, 1, interpolate = FALSE)
```

[image]